# SQL Query using NOT in not working

Tags: mysql

I have the following database:

```
-------------------
| Id | Word      |
------------------
| 1  | unusual   |
------------------
| 2  | wedding   |
------------------
| 3  | highness  |
```

with many more words. I am running the following query but its not giving me the correct result.

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word NOT IN ('unusual','mutton','wedding','highness','intellect') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Even when I specify which words I don't want being randomly selected, I still get some of the words in the list if I execute that query enough times. For example the query above gave me the word "highness" on the 3 time of running that query.

Comment: are you sure that all the values in the database are lower case and without leading or trailing space?

Comment: You could use a full text index and do a binary mode search like 
MATCH (word) AGAINST ("-unusual -mutton -wedding -highness -intellect" IN BINARY MODE). Might be more efficient.

Comment: can you explain what you mean^